# Comparing two matrices in an If block

Tags: matrix, evaluation, infinite-loop, logic

I want to find out for what value of n `MatrixPower[u, n] == IdentityMatrix[3]`

```
u = {{0, 0, I}, {-I, 0, 0}, {0, -1, 0}};
n = 1;
While[n < 10, 
 If[{MatrixPower[u, n] == IdentityMatrix[3]}, Print["TRUTH"]]; n++]
```

I chose `n=10` because I know the answer is 6, but it doesn't print 6. What is the problem here?

Answer (score 2):

```
u = {{0, 0, I}, {-I, 0, 0}, {0, -1, 0}};

soln = Solve[
   {MatrixPower[u, n] == IdentityMatrix[3],
    n > 0}, n][[1]]

(*  {n -> ConditionalExpression[-6 C[1], 
   C[1] ∈ Integers && C[1] <= -1]}  *)
```

Verifying the solution

```
Assuming[{Element[C[1], Integers], C[1] <= -1},
 MatrixPower[u, n] == IdentityMatrix[3] /. soln // FullSimplify]

(*  True  *)
```

Or for specific values

```
And @@ Table[
  MatrixPower[u, n] == IdentityMatrix[3],
  {n, 6, 72, 6}]

(*  True  *)
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider this illustrative example:

```
x = 2;
If[{x > 0}, Print["positive"]]
```

> If[{True}, Print["positive"]]

The thing is, the first argument of `If` should yield `True` or `False`; in the above example, it yields `{True}`, which due to the curly brackets is different than `True`. Hence one should type

```
If[x > 0, Print["positive"]]
```

> positive

---

So the reason why the OP's syntax doesn't give anything are the brackets which should be removed:

```
u = {{0, 0, I}, {-I, 0, 0}, {0, -1, 0}};
n = 1;
While[n < 10, 
 If[MatrixPower[u, n] == IdentityMatrix[3], Print["TRUTH"]]; n++]
```

> TRUTH

But "it doesn't print 6", so let's modify the `Print` part:

```
While[n < 10, 
 If[MatrixPower[u, n] == IdentityMatrix[3], 
  Print["TRUTH for n=" <> ToString[n]]]; n++]
```

> TRUTH for n=6

The problem with the above syntax is that `n = 1` has to be set at each evaluation of the `While` cell; if it's not, `n` is assigned a value of `10`. To avoid this, use `Block` which makes `n` local for the `While`:

```
Block[{n = 1},
 While[n < 10, 
  If[MatrixPower[u, n] == IdentityMatrix[3], 
   Print["TRUTH for n=" <> ToString[n]]]; n++]
 ]
```

> TRUTH for n=6